# Docker private registry, docker push is forbidden

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I setup a private registry, which run fine. Docker 1.10. I choose to change the host, and recreate the certificate. All run fine on my server, but on my customer server I can't push an image to the registry :

```
unable to ping registry endpoint https://my.customer.private.hostname:5000/v0/
 v2 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://my.customer.private.hostname:5000/v2/: Forbidden
 v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://my.customer.private.hostname:5000/v1/_ping: Forbidden
```

I can't find anybody else talking about 'forbidden' answer on Google. Where can I search to understand ? 
I already deleted the container, the image, uninstalled docker, reinstalled docker but still the same error. The only thing I do not delete is the thinpool used to store docker data (devicemapper).

Comment: You changed the host, did you update dns records?

Comment: Yes, and curl -k https://my.customer.private.hostname:5000/v2/_catalog give me a json record with my docker images.

Comment: First of all we need to know if its a certificate issue. try `--insecure-registry myregistry:5000` option

Comment: My docker registry have a certificate built for it, and the CA certificate is given to each Docker installation in /etc/docker/certs.d/myregistry.domain.tld:5000/ca.crt, so my registry is not insecure. But I will try to be sure.

Comment: Have you done a `docker login my.customer.private.hostname:5000`? I'd preface that with a `docker logout my.customer.private.hostname:5000` to make sure an old login isn't sitting around.

Comment: No, but there is no login on my private registry. I will try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a systemd conf file for docker :

> /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf

with

> [Service] 
>   Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy:3128"
>   Environment="NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.0/8"

The registry IP was not localhost, so I needed to add the host to the NO_PROXY variable. I still not undestand why the first host worked. Restarting the registry container without https (http only) and using tcpdump help us to resolve this issue.

Comment: Hooray: In my case, we used to have proxy, and no longer do, so this reminded me to delete the proxy settings.

Answer (score 0):

For me it is very strange that docker is trying to reach via https to 5000 port and then you made a curl with http to the same port and it worked.

Probably you are doing: `docker pull my.customer.private.hostname:5000 xxx/yyy` instead of `docker pull my.customer.private.hostname xxx/yyy`

Regards